# Postgis ST_GeomFromWKB return Invalid endian flag value encountered

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2

I'm trying to test if a polygon is contain in an other polygon.

In database, we have a field with geometrics datas called "wkb_geometry".

I have a fonctionnal request :

```
SELECT *, ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(parcels.wkb_geometry)),ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(parcel_geometry_datas))) FROM parcels
```

PostGis documentation say a function exist for wkb_datas (without use ST_AsText) : ST_GeomFromWKB

When I try, for example

```
SELECT *, ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromWKB(parcels.wkb_geometry), ST_GeomFromWKB('0106000020E6100000010000000103000000010000000600000045172F713F3BB7BFD3B2FF4B63A545405C6CFF6F9120B7BF1F48DE3994A54540B42BE395DA41B7BFD27C845094A54540B4226AA2CF47B7BFD855928664A5454040B676ECB13EB7BF68CEFA9463A5454045172F713F3BB7BFD3B2FF4B63A54540')) FROM parcels LIMIT 10;
```

Postgis return

```
Invalid endian flag value encountered
```

I don't understand what is the problem and what is "endian flag value", can you help ?

Thanks

Comment: Update : found ! just setting parameter ::geometry after the second ST_GeomFromWKB

Comment: Go ahead and put that as an answer! That fixed my issue - and you can mark it as accepted for future people. Otherwise, I'll do it. :P